# Unsupported post request. Object with ID '1784XX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We tested the access token using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ and confirmed that the following scopes are available with the page:

pages_show_list, pages_messaging, instagram_basic, whatsapp_business_management, instagram_manage_messages, pages_manage_metadata, whatsapp_business_messaging, and public_profile.

However, we are unable to send a response back to the incoming webhook as we are receiving a 400 response with error code 100 and an error subcode 33.

Other important points:

We have connected two Instagram accounts to a FB page and are using one Instagram account to message the other for testing.

2.The access token is scoped to the parent FB page to which these Instagram accounts are connected. Is this acceptable, or do we need an access token specifically created for the Instagram page? If so, how do we create one?

Comment: What exactly is "send a response back" supposed to mean? What API endpoint are you trying to use?